# Moment generating function of the maximum of two normal random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions, bivariate-distributions

I found this paper [here](https://www.gwern.net/docs/conscientiousness/2008-nadarajah.pdf). In equations (5) - (6), the paper says that suppose $(X_1,X_2)$ are jointly normal with means and variances $(\mu_1,\mu_2),(\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2)$, define $X = \max\{X_1,X_2\}$. Then the moment generating function for $X$ is defined in (5)-(6).

I'm trying derive that result, but I'm totally stuck. Can I get a hint? I know how to derive the mgf for normal random variables, but not the maximum of two non-iid normals.

Comment: Equation (6) has a stray ! sign in the middle of the right-hand side.  Presumably this is a typo?

Comment: I think so. Assuming that it is a typo, could you tell me how to start deriving the result?

Comment: In fact I don't know.  It looks like a calculus exercise, perhaps involving integration by parts, tedious but not fundamentally difficult.  Have you looked at the cited sources, refs 8, 9, 10, and 11?